# Vuex state property does not update

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex

I'm developing a simple social media at the moment. I have a problem. `token` state property doesn't update at all, even when there is a `token` item in the localStorage. **[Here](https://github.com/loglinn05/catalyst) is my unfinished project on Github.** And here is the store where the `token` property is stored (path: `resources/js/store/modules/middleware.js`):

```js
const state = {
    user: {
        loggedIn: false,
        isSubscribed: false,
        token: localStorage.getItem('token') || ''
    },
}
const actions = {}
const mutations = {}
const getters = {
    auth(state) {
        return state.user
    }
}

export default {
    namespaced: false,
    state,
    actions,
    mutations,
    getters
}
```

At first I thought that the state just updates before `token` item appears. So I decided to print the token in the console after 10 seconds (path of the file below: `resources/js/middleware/auth.js`):

```js
export default function ({ next, store }) {
    if (!store.getters.auth.token) {
        console.log(store.getters.auth.token);
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(store.getters.auth.token);
        }, 10000)
        return next('login')
    }
    return next()
}
```

But the token was still an empty string. Here is how the console looks:
[image: The console]

If you need something else to understand my question, feel free to ask!

Comment: It's unclear why you expect it to something else. You don't set auth.token anywhere in listed code

Comment: You should be probably first storing token in your local storage at some point. Probably on the successful response on login page:  localStorage.setItem('token', value)

Comment: How are you setting the token in the local storage?

Comment: @equi, @NehaSoni, @EstusFlask, I'm setting the token in `loginUser()` in `auth.js` (path: `resources/js/store/modules/auth.js`). Also, I've linked to the [project repository](https://github.com/loglinn05/catalyst/) at the beginning of the post already.

Comment: You seems to expect the localStorage to be in sync with vuex, and that's not true, the initial value of the state will be retrieved from the localStorage but that's it, it won't pick up updates, unless you update both the localStorage and vuex state in your loginUser function.

Comment: What you can do : on your `setLoggedIn` mutation do something like : `state.token = localStorage.getItem('token');` or better create a `setToken` mutation, and do : `ctx.commit('setToken', response.data.access_token);` and let the mutation update the localStorage for you. That way both localStorage and vuex state will be set at the same time.

Comment: @Lk77, thank you so much! Your way worked! All the best!